# Location of STDOUT storage in Java application running as a Windows Service

Tags: java, windows, heap-memory, stdout

I have a Java application that is run as a background process to a Windows Service application.

When issuing a console output statement, such as `System.out.println`, where does that output get stored.  Does it get stored in Windows storage, or does it remain in the JVM heap storage?

Comment: "Stored" meaning what?

Comment: Whether and where it gets stored (and even whether it is in fact safe to write output at all) depends entirely on the windows service application in question.  Neither Windows nor the JVM will do anything to "store" it if the service application doesn't.

Comment: Since there's no console for it to go to, the message should get "stored" someplace until it is retrieved.  I just don't know if its in the O/S memory pool or in the JVM heap.

Comment: @HarryJohnston The Java process is run as a background process, invoked by the Windows Service.  The application is suffering from a slow memory leak and I don't know if it's a result of some console output messages or whether there's something else I need to look at.

Comment: @ke4ktz: neither Windows nor Java ever promised you that they would store the output from your application.  Unless the service application promised to do so, generating output from your application is against the rules, i.e., is a bug in your code.  Fix that first, then see if the memory leak is still present.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Actually, it's a third-party library that logs to the console unless it's explicitly turned off (Level.NONE).  Before I sent out a fix for just that issue, I figured I would check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer has been found.

A third-party library had a method that was not turning off console output of the log4j logging when a customer `Appender` was created.  There were two methods to accomplish this, only one of them performed the operation properly.

I switched to the second method and the console messages stopped when the custom `Appender` was created.  I re-ran the job that was failing after 18 hours.  Right now, it is at 3.5 days (84 hours) and still going strong.

Therefore, it can be determined that if there is no process that will take the console output (`System.out`), those output messages will be stored by the JVM in heap storage.  Eventually the JVM heap storage will be exhausted and the application will crash.